# ts An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor

Tags: typescript, async-await

Hello I'm Using async/await in my TypeScript Project, But I Get this log:

*[ts] An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.*

How Can I Solve That?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

As the error message says, add `lib: es2015` to your tsconfig.json

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2015" ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE: if this doesn't work for you, try this:

JetBrains IDE such as WebStorm, use its own implementation by default. Make sure you configure it to use TypeScript language service instead.

For Visual Studio, the project files and `tsconfig.json` are mutually exclusive. You will need to configure your project directly.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3983#issuecomment-123861491

Comment: `{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    }
}` this is my tsconfig.json How Should I edit?

Comment: Where to specify this in Visual Studio 2017? It does not have tsconfig.json

Comment: @AkashKava You've to create `tsconfig.json` by your self.

Comment: @katopz I did, but VS does not care about it, I found that `csproj` file has some extra xml elements to enable/disable such things.

Comment: I had to restart my IDE (WebStorm) to see the result.

Comment: I have that ("lib": ["dom", "es2015"]) but it still complains

Comment: Are you using visual studio? It have a different way to setup. Not in tsconfig.json

Comment: For webstorm, check your setting to make sure it uses TypeScript language service.

Comment: The issue for me was that I also needed to update the "include" path. (See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848802/webstorm-an-async-function-or-method-in-es5-es3-requires-the-promise-construc?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848802)

Comment: I had to include ``"dom"`` in the ``"lib"`` array as well or I get other errors.

Comment: For vscode IDE. If your tsconfig is correct make sure it is resolved and not falling back to defaults.

Comment: Make sure you are not passing the filename if you run this via the command line. It should be `npx tsc` not `npx tsc myFile.ts`

Answer (score 32):

Try this package which contains type definitions for es6-promise

`npm install --save @types/es6-promise`

Comment: If your target is node, `npm i -D @types/node@16` works too.

Answer (score 15):

If you are on VS, delete the tsconfig.json and right click the project in Solution Explorer, then click on **Properties->TypeScript Build in General** change the followings

- ECMAScript version: ECMAScript 6
- Module System: ES2015

Comment: @LukePighetti project in solution-explorer

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had simply accidentally deleted my "return" statement in the function, and this error was showing until I put it back.

Comment: That was exactly my case! Tried everything before noticing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For me the error occurred in my testing files inside `src/tests` folder. Since I use `ts-node` for testing the `.ts` files directly, I excluded `src/tests/*` in my `tsconfig.json`. As soon as I deleted the line the error was gone (which makes sense in the end).

Just in case someone else is struggling with this in his testing files.

EDIT: Of course you need to configure your `--lib` option correctly as outlined in the accepted answer. My `tsconfig.json --lib` option works as following:

```
"lib": [
    "es2018",
    "dom"
]
```

Comment: I compile with `tsc` an async function in a ts file on the client, not on the server. I use `document.getElementById` in the function. When using `dom` with `--lib` as param to `tsc` it works. So I think `dom` is needed if you are on the client.

Answer (score 4):

Add "es2015.promise" in tsconfig.json - in "lib" = like this :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "dom",
            "es2015.promise"
        ],
        "types": [
            "mocha"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "../../../out",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "tests"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the "lib": "es2015.promise" for that specific error

Answer (score 2):

VS2019 does not seem to recognize the tsconfig.json file, so LIB options will not change the application.  This is a way to add the PROMISE for typescript to accept ASYNC AWAIT.

```
export function AD(first: any, second: any, callBack: any)
{
    const rtn = async (dispatch: any): Promise<void> =>
    {
        await axios.post(TYPE.URI, { // provide a string of a URI to post into
            parm1: first,
            parm2: second
        })
            .then(data => // or you can use response instead of data as a name
            {
                console.log("data from call next");
                console.log(data);
                dispatch({ type: TYPES.AD, payload: data.data });
                if (callBack)
                {
                    callBack(data);
                }
            })
    }
    return rtn;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tsc --target ES6`

This was the solution for me !

Comment: this helped with WebStorm!

Answer (score 2):

I am using JetBrains Rider 2022.2.3 and had the following in my `.csproj` project file (I am not using the `tsconfig.json` file):

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES6</TypeScriptTarget>    
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The above meant that I could compile my TypeScript just fine, but Rider was still showing same "use --lib option" error message until I set the target to ES6 for TypeScript Language Service as well. Do it as follows in settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you compile or watch your typescript file via `tsc index.ts --watch` add `--lib` flag to it with its value (in our case es2015), it should look like this 
`tsc index.ts --watch --lib es2015` 
for better work `tsc index.ts --watch --lib "es2015, es2016, dom"` - when it can't read dom from tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other responses which suggest adding the lib as follows

```
...
"lib": ["es2015"],
...
```

the typescript server must also be restarted.

On Visual Studio Code you can do it using the command-palette option (default is `CTRL + Shift + P` on Windows) and searching for `Restart TS Server`

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to solve it!
My command on the terminal:
`yarn tsc main.ts && nodejs main.js`
My error message:

```js
main.ts:1:16 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.

1 async function main() {
                 ~~~~


Found 2 errors.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What I did to solve it, was referencing the tsconfig.json file.
My tsconfig.json file was like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": [
            "ES2015",
            "DOM"
        ]
    }
}
```

And my terminal command is like this:
`yarn tsc -p ./tsconfig.json && nodejs main.js`
If I want to run other .ts file I simply do:
`yarn tsc -p ./tsconfig.json && nodejs file_name.js`

Answer (score -3):

I am using VS2017 v15.8.2 and Typescript 2.4.2 in an Angular 4 project (under a class library project in my solution, not a typescript project).
I was able to remove the error/warning in VS by disabling the **JavaScript language service**:

**Options => Text Editor => JavaScript/TypeScript => Language Service**

**Restart VS.**

Hope this helps.