# WebStorm, An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor

Tags: typescript, async-await, webstorm

I try to write tests in typescript (ES6) using WebStorm IDE. E.g.:

```
// Imports...

describe('Message', () => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(bodyParser.json());

    const messageService = { findAll: () => ['test'] };

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            modules: [MessageModule],
        })...
    });

    // Tests...
});
```

However WebStorm IDE shows following error at `async () =>`

> TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the Promise
>   constructor. Make sure you have a declaration for the Promise
>   constructor or include ES2015 in your --lib option.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I read [ts An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555378/ts-an-async-function-or-method-in-es5-es3-requires-the-promise-constructor) and tried adding

```
"lib": [ "es2015" ]
```

however it does not have any effect. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I added this and still this is giving me errors in normal source files. What can be wrong? This is giving me this error in dynamic imports

Comment: Also, I'm using `awesome-typescript-loader` as typescript loader

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding

```
"lib": [ "es2015" ]
```

to *tsconfig.json* should fix the issue.
However it seems that your spec files are not included in your *tsconfig.json* (check `"include":[]` and `"exclude":[]` values). So the Typescript service must be using a different *tsconfig.json* for your files (may be a default one, if no *tsconfig.json* files that include your specs can be found)
To fix the issue, make sure to specify the `lib` property in config that is used for your spec files processing

Answer (score 22):

## Solution without editing the project sources

I had this problem with IntelliJ and resolved by changing my IDE settings:

**Settings** -> **Language & Frameworks** -> **TypeScript**

then in the "Options" field add:

```
--lib es2015
```

[image]

Comment: this answer!  My problem wasn't the code, but WebStorm!  my code ran fine through WebStorm even though it was giving this error

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": ["es2015"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

adding `"lib":["es2015"]` to `"compilerOptions"` as per @lena's answer and Removing `**/*.spec.ts` from `"exclude":[]` and adding it to `"include":[]` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add "lib": [ "es2015" ] in tsconfig.json under compilerOptions as

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [ "es2015" ]
  }
}
```