# Vite + Vue 3 SFC: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vite

I have this code, Vue 3 + Vite:

```js
<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

const store = useStore();

const playlists = computed(() => store.getters["playlists/allPlaylists"]);
const playlistsCount = computed(
  () => store.getters["playlists/allPlaylistsCount"]
);
const selectPlaylist = (playlist) => {
  store.dispatch("playlists/selectPlaylist", playlist);
}

onMounted(async () => { await store.dispatch('playlists/getAllPlaylists') })
</script>
```

I'm not using typescript, I use Visual Studio Code.

I get warned by the IDE on the `onMounted` method with:

`An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.ts(2705)`

my jsconfig.json

```json
{
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

anything I can do to make the IDE error go away?

Comment: You're not using TS but VSC does. You're certainly not using ES5 because of Vite, so it needs to be adjusted the other way, `target: "esnext"` in compilerOptions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ts An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555378/ts-an-async-function-or-method-in-es5-es3-requires-the-promise-constructor)