# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I am using mocha `"mocha": "^7.2.0",` to do an unit test, when I run the test command:

```
"test": "cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT='test/tsconfig.test.json' mocha test/**/**",
```

shows error like this:

```
➜  js-wheel git:(main) ✗ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.17
$ cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT='test/tsconfig.test.json' mocha test/**/**

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/test/utils/time.test.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Object.file: (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:72:15)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:85:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:13:42)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:303:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:230:58)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:244:11)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:28:20)
    at async singleRun (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:149:3)
    at async exports.runMocha (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:186:5)
    at async Object.exports.handler (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:319:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

some told that I could remove `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, but I could not remove it, I need to use the es6 import. I checked the tsconfig.json and the `esModuleInterop` config is already be true. what should I do to fix this problem? this is the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "esnext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    
    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "lib": [ "DOM","ES2015" ], /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555378/ts-an-async-function-or-method-in-es5-es3-requires-the-promise-constructor */
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "moduleResolution":"node",                            /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@net/*":["net/*"],
      "@auth/*":["auth/*"],
      "@utils/*":["utils/*"],
      "@model/*":["model/*"],
    },
    // Note: To transform paths for both the output .js and .d.ts files, you need both of the below entries
    "plugins": [
      // Transform paths in output .js files
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
      { "transform": "ts-transformer-keys/transformer" },

      // Transform paths in output .d.ts files (Include this line if you output declarations files)
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ]                                 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

I also tried this command:

```
"test": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/**",
```

still did not work. Also tried to use ts-mocha:

```
"test": "ts-mocha -p tsconfig.json test/**/**",
```

dit not work. tweak the tsconfig.json:

```
"module": "CommonJS"
```

still did not work.

Comment: You're setting `TS_NODE_PROJECT` but running straight `mocha`, not [`ts-mocha`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/ts-mocha#usage), [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#shell), or [`node -r tsnode/register`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#node-flags). Is there some other config where you'd expect Node to handle TypeScript without explicit configuration?