# ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

I am new in typescript, when I compiled code it compiled properly but when I run program using node
I got this error  ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'D:\projects\pro8\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///D:/projects/pro8/await.js:40:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)
```

typescript code

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const baseApi = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";
const userApi = "https://reqres.in/api/user";
interface Employee {
    id: number
    employee_name: string
    employee_salary: number
    employee_age: number
    profile_image: string
}
const fetchAllEmployees = async (url: string): Promise<Employee[]> => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const { data }:any = await response.json();
  return data;
};

const fetchEmployee = async (url: string, id: number): Promise<Record<string, string>> => {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}/${id}`);
  const { data }:any = await response.json();
  return data;
};
const generateEmail = (name: string): string => {
  return `${name.split(" ").join(".")}@company.com`;
};

const runAsyncFunctions = async () => {
  try {
    const employees = await fetchAllEmployees(baseApi);
    Promise.all(
      employees.map(async user => {
        const userName = await fetchEmployee(userApi, user.id);
        const emails = generateEmail(userName.name);
        return emails;
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
runAsyncFunctions();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "pro8",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.21.0",
    "eslint": "^8.14.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

I tried to solve this error [ts An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555378/ts-an-async-function-or-method-in-es5-es3-requires-the-promise-constructor)

any answer not working in my case

so please give me solution if any

Comment: `at file:///D:/projects/pro8/await.js:40:1`

Comment: @hoangdv don't know what you talking about can you please elaborate on it

Comment: This is the main information about your error. In other words, the error may become from this file, so let's check it. Something went wrong, you have a `js` file in a typescript project.

Comment: What is the contents of `index.js`? What is the node command you are trying to execute? Since it is a typescript file, you need to check what is generated source code, try to paste generated source code of the main typescript file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try and remove `"type": "module"` from `package.json`. I had this issue before and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I tried this not working getting other error  " ts An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor" but it works without promises and changing in tsconfig file "target": "es2016"

Comment: This seemed to work for me!

Comment: can you explain why should we do like this?

Comment: This is not a sufficient answer, please explain more.

Comment: Explain please OP