# Typescript: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-promise, tsconfig, tsc

I try to compile an example code (app.ts) using an async function by using VScode but cannot get it without errors.

```
const request = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto');
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
}
```

Got this error message :

> "Typescript: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor".

Now I added `"lib": [ "ES2015", "DOM"]` to the tsconfig.json file and did a "tsc" in terminal and then tried it again "tsc app.ts". But I still get the same error.
 I saw other people resolved this problem by adding these lines to the tsconfig.json, but it didn´t help for me. The compiler seems to take into account the tsconfig.json cause I tested by changing the outDir. "tsc" or "tsc -p tsconfig.json" are successful.

Target in compiler options is "es2016"

Comment: you have to istall this package too `npm install --save @types/es6-promise`

Comment: Unsure if relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68318759/3509591

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48976287/13488990) may help too

Comment: `npm install --save @types/es6-promise` and `"lib": [ "ES2015", "DOM" , "es2015.promise" ]` did not help

Comment: Include your full tsconfig